# Child Class editing Parent Class Property

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, properties

I've looked at similar questions like this, and none of the solutions offered within them seems to answer my question.

This is the code I have so far (just learning OOP):

```
<?php

class page {
    var $ot;
    function begin(){
        $this->ot = '';
    }
    function finish(){
        echo $this->ot;
    }


class forms extends page {
    function __construct($form_action, $form_type){
        $this->ot .= '<form action=' . $form_action . ' method=' . $form_type . ' />';
    }
    function create_input($type, $name){
        $this->ot .= '<input type="' . $type . '" name="' . $name . '" /><br />';   
    }
    function create_submit($value){
        $this->ot .= '<input type="submit" value="' . $value . '" />';
    }
    function __destruct(){
        $this->ot .= '</form>';
    }       
}

class labels extends page {
    function create_label($label){
        $this->ot .= '<label>' . $label . ' </label>';
    }
}

$page = new page();
$page->begin();

$newform = new forms('/class_lib.php', 'GET');
$newlabels = new labels();

$newlabels->create_label('Username:');
$newform->create_input('text', 'username');
$newlabels->create_label('Password:');
$newform->create_input('password', 'password');

$page->finish();

 ?>
```

For some reason, this code does not output anything to the browser. However, if I change the child classes *forms* and *labels* to echo their output instead of storing it in the parent variable the code seems to spring to life and works as intended.

Excuse my ignorance as I am new to OOP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The objects are not really connected.

You create three new objects, but they never reference each other.

Try this

```
// Create a new form
$newform = new forms('/class_lib.php', 'GET');

$newform->create_input('text', 'username');
$newform->create_input('password', 'password');

// Output the form, it can use the finish() method because it extends page    
$newform->finish();
```

This will work and output the `<input>` elements, but your `label` class isn't plugged in to the `$newForm` to do anything, its just created and is completely separate.

EDIT - bored this evening....

You will need PHP5 to run this, its not perfect, but its a good start! I have defined the following an interface called renderable and classes called element, input, label and form

```
// An interface describes the methods that a class must use
interface renderable
{
    // Any classes that implement the renderabe interface must define a method called render()
    function render();
}

// This abstract class can never be created, so you can never do new element(), it implements renderable
abstract class element implements renderable
{
    // Set up some variables for all elemnts
    var $attribs = array();
    var $name = "";
    var $type = "";    

        // The construct for a element needs a type and a name
    function __construct($type, $name)
    {        
        $this->name = $name;        
        $this->type = $type;            
    }

    // Set an attribute for the element
    function setAttribute($name, $value)
    {
        $this->attribs[$name] = $value;
    }

    // Get the name of this element
    function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    // The render function outputs an element
    function render()
    {
        // Output the start of the element eg <input
        echo "<" . $this->type . " ";

        // each attribute eg class='blue'
        foreach($this->attribs as $name => $value)
            echo " " . $name . "='" . $value ."' ";         

        // end the element
        echo " />";     

        echo "<br />";
    }
}

// The input element extends element but is not abstract
class input extends element
{
    // Nothing is overridden here from the parent class element
}

// The label element extends element but is not abstract
class label extends element
{
    // Define a new var called label, this is special for the label element
    var $label = "";

    // Override the contruct for element to only accept a name, this
    // is because the label element type will always be label
    function __construct($name)
    {        
        $this->name = $name;        
        $this->type = "label";            
    }

    // Set the label var
    function setLabel($label)
    {
        $this->label = $label;
    }   

    // Override the render function, this means that label has its own render function
    // and does not use the function from the abstract class element
    function render()
    {
            echo "<" . $this->type . " ";

            foreach($this->attribs as $name => $value)
                echo  " " . $name . "='" . $value ."' ";            

            echo " >";

            //  Here the special label content is displayed
            echo $this->label;

            echo "</label>";        
    }
}

// A form extends element
class form extends element
{
    // A form has some new vars
    var $elements = array();
    var $labels = array();    

    var $action;
    var $method;

    // Override the contruct and use name, action and method
    // There are default values for action and method so they are not required
    function __construct($name, $action = "/", $method = "GET")
    {        
        $this->name = $name;        
        $this->type = "form";            
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->method = $method;
    }

    // Add a new element to the form along with its label
    function appendElement($element, $label)
    {
        // Add these to an array inside this class
        $this->elements[$element->getName()] = $element;
        $this->labels[$label->getName()] = $label;   
    }

    // Override the render function
    function render()
    {
        // Output the form's start along with the method and action
        echo '<' . $this->type. ' ' . 'action="' . $this->action . '" method="' . $this->method . '" />';

        // Iterate over the array of elments and render each one
        foreach($this->elements as $name => $ele)
        {
            // Render the label for the current element
            $this->labels[$name]->render();
            // Render the element
                $ele->render();
        }

        // End the form
        echo "</form>";
    }
}

// Create form with name, action and method
$form = new form("login", "/login.php", "POST");


// Create input username
$ele = new input("input", "username");
// Set type
$ele->setAttribute("type", "text");
// Set a class
$ele->setAttribute("class", "blue");

// Create a label for the username long with its content
$label = new label("username");
$label->setLabel("Username: ");

// Add the username element and its label
$form->appendElement($ele, $label);

// Repeat for password
$ele = new input("input", "password");
$ele->setAttribute("type", "password");

$label = new label("password");
$label->setLabel("Password: ");

$form->appendElement($ele, $label);

// Render the form
$form->render();
```

Comment: This works, but I am required to now do $newform->finish() and $newlabels->finish() at the end of the page. Additionally, since there are two different variables, the HTML is not outputted in the order I wanted it to be. Any way to fix this?

Comment: ^ This was before your edit. Should label be a subclass of newform? Would that still result in seperate $ot variables?

Answer (score 1):

`$ot` is an object-property. This means, that every object of the class `page` or any subclass has its own "version" of `$ot`. Now you instanciate some objects and set some values, but at the end, when you call `$page->finish();` `$page->ot` is empty anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In OOP you have the classes (types) and instances of the classes (objects). The `$ot` property is what you call an instance variable, it belongs to the instances (objects) you create and is not a property of the class itself.

By making forms a subclass of page, you get what you call a "is a" relationship between the classes. That means that forms will inherit the structure of the page class. Modifying the property of a subclass object will not affect the superclass objects or any other object in this case.

When you first create a page object, that object has a `$ot` property. When you create a object of type forms, that object has its own `$ot` property.

To understand the concepts of OOP I would recommend you to read some tutorials. You could start by reading the Class, Instance and Inheritance parts of this wikipedia article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 1):

Since you're learning OOP, it's time to learn about [`Abstract` Classes (PHP Manual)](https://www.php.net/abstract)!

An abstract class is a sort of skeleton class that defines a series of generic functions.  An abstract class can never be instantiated (i.e., you cannot call `new AbstractClass`), but can be `extend`ed by other classes.  This allows us to define something generic and repeatable, say, and HTML Element, and then extend that to specific HTML elements as time goes on.  Here is a sample implementation of that concept.

##WARNING: I am not saying that *this* implementation is a great idea; learning purposes only!

###First, some abstract classes to define how this stuff ought to work.

```
abstract class HTMLWriter
{
    protected $html = '';
    protected $tagName = null;
    protected $selfClosing = false;
    protected $elements = array();
    protected $attributes = array();
    
    protected $closed = false;
    
    abstract public function __construct();
    
    public function addElement(HTMLWriter $element)
    {
        if ($this->closed || $this->selfClosing) {
            return;
        }
        $element->close(); // automatic!
        
        $this->elements[] = $element->write();
    }
    
    public function addElements() {
        foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
            if ($arg instanceof HTMLWriter) {
                $this->addElement($arg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function addAttribute($name, $value)
    {
        return $this->attributes[$name] = $value;
    }
    
    public function write()
    {
        if (!$this->closed) {
            $this->close();
        }
        return $this->html;
    }
    
    public function close()
    {
        $this->closed = true;
        $this->html = '<' . $this->tagName;
        foreach ($this->attributes AS $attr => $val) {
            $this->html .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $val . '"';
        }
        if ($this->selfClosing) {
            $this->html .= '/>';
            return;
        }
        $this->html .= '>';
        foreach($this->elements as $elem) {
            $this->html .= $elem;
        }
        $this->html .= '</' . $this->tagName . '>';
    }
}

abstract class HTMLWriterWithTextNodes extends HTMLWriter
{
    //abstract public function __construct();

    public function addText($text)
    {
        $this->elements[] = htmlentities($text);
    }
    
    public function addTextRaw($text)
    {
        $this->elements[] = $text;
    }
}
```

###And then the concrete implementations of those classes:
*note: a concrete class is any non-abstract class, although this term loses its meaning when applied to classes that are not extensions of abstract classes.*

```
class Form extends HTMLWriter
{
    public function __construct($action, $method, $can_upload = false)
    {
        $this->tagName = 'form';
        $this->addAttribute('action', $action);
        $this->addAttribute('method', $method);
        if ($can_upload) {
            $this->addAttribte('enctype','multipart/form-data');
        }
    }
}

class Input extends HTMLWriter
{
    public function __construct($type, $name, $id = null)
    {
        $this->tagName = 'input';
        $this->selfClosing = true;
        $this->addAttribute('type', $type);
        $this->addAttribute('name', $name);
        if (!is_null($id)) {
            $this->addAttribute('id', $id);
        }
    }
    
    // overrides
    public function addElement()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class Label extends HTMLWriterWithTextNodes
{
    public function __construct($labelText = null, $for = null)
    {
        $this->tagName = 'label';
        
        if (!is_null($labelText)) {
            $this->elements[] = $labelText;
        }
        
        if (!is_null($for)) {
            $this->addAttribute('for', $for);
        }
    }
}

class GenericElement extends HTMLWriterWithTextNodes
{
    public function __construct($tagName, $selfClosing = false)
    {
        if (empty($tagName)) {
            $this->closed = true;
            $this->html = '';
            return;
        }
        $this->tagName = $tagName;
        $this->selfClosing = (bool)$selfClosing;
    }
}
```

###Finally, let's instantiate and use our new classes

```
$form = new Form('/class_lib.php','get');

$username = new Input('text','username','username');
$password = new Input('password','password','password');
$submit = new Input('submit','login');
$submit->addAttribute('value','login');
$ulabel = new Label('Username: ', 'username');
$plabel = new Label('Password: ','password');
$br = new GenericElement('br',true);

$form->addElements(
    $ulabel,  $username, $br,
    $plabel,  $password, $br,
    $submit
);

echo $form->write();
```

###Output:
Username: 
Password:

Hooray for abstract classes!